# Eigenvalues of matrix summation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be symmetric positive definite matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n$. Can we express the eigenvalues of $I-A$ using eigenvalues of $A$? I can't find properties of eigenvalue related to this problem.

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, what is $(I-A)v$?

Comment: Alternatively, det$(A - \lambda I) = $ det$((A - I) - (\lambda - 1) I)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we could diagonalize the matrix $A$. It isn't necessarily true that we can, but if we could we would have all of the eigenvalues along the diagonal. If we subtract the identity matrix, what happens to each eigenvalue?

Now in this case, it isn't necessarily true that we have a diagonal representation, so consider an eigenvector $v$ corresponding to some eigenvalue $\lambda$.

$$ (I-A)v=Iv-Av$$
does it not?
$$ Iv=1v, Av=\lambda v.$$
Do you know why this holds? This gives us
$$ Iv-Av=(1-\lambda)v.$$
Can you see now what happens to each eigenvalue?